# registering a model with the admin site, Once I try to define the entry Model system shows unproperly configured exception

Tags: python, django

1. > (ll_env) C:\learning_log>python manage.py test  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 21, in 
   >       main()   File "manage.py", line 17, in main
   >       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
   >   line 381, in execute_from_command_line
   >       utility.execute()   File "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
   >   line 375, in execute
   >       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\test.py",
   >   line 23, in run_from_argv
   >       super().run_from_argv(argv)   File "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
   >   line 315, in run_from_argv
   >       parser = self.create_parser(argv[0], argv[1])   File "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
   >   line 289, in create_parser
   >       self.add_arguments(parser)   File "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\test.py",
   >   line 44, in add_arguments
   >       test_runner_class = get_runner(settings, self.test_runner)   File
   >   "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py",
   >   line 303, in get_runner
   >       test_runner_class = test_runner_class or settings.TEST_RUNNER   File
   >   "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__.py",
   >   line 79, in **getattr**
   >       self._setup(name)   File "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__.py",
   >   line 66, in _setup
   >       self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)   File "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__.py",
   >   line 157, in **init**
   >       mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)   File "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib__init__.py",
   >   line 127, in import_module
   >       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
   >   File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
   >   File "", line 967, in
   >   _find_and_load_unlocked   File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked   File "", line 728, in exec_module   File
   >   "", line 219, in
   >   _call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\learning_log\learning_log\settings.py", line 16, in 
   >       django.setup()   File "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py",
   >   line 19, in setup
   >       configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)   File
   >   "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__.py",
   >   line 79, in **getattr**
   >       self._setup(name)   File "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__.py",
   >   line 66, in _setup
   >       self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)   File "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__.py",
   >   line 176, in **init**
   >       raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY
   >   setting must not be empty.

Comment: Can you share the traceback? The error may have been caused by another error in your settings

Comment: hello there ok this is my wsgi.py
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'learning_log.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()

Comment: Can you share the full traceback - the error

Comment: Yes, I will once I learn how can I do that.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: You're calling `django.setup()` in your settings, you shouldn't do that

Comment: I did remove the calling as you advise and change the ("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings") and I can see the changes. thank you, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Error has nothing to do with your model or admin site. You are running your Django Program  with a settings file that doesn't have a `SECRET_KEY`

Comment: I'll update my answer if you can share your file structure, wsgiy.py, and the command you use to run project. In the meantime, this is why you are getting that error @Allen Suarez